# How to construct price time series from price changes using MS-Access 2007 queries?

Tags: ms-access

### Background

I've got a table of price **changes** `tblPriceChanges` of various items `tblItems` (example below - data made up):

```
[tblPriceChanges]:
Timestamp       Item    Price
9AM 01/01/2013  Orange  50p
9AM 01/01/2013  Apple   30p
2PM 01/01/2013  Pen     80p
2PM 02/01/2013  Orange  55p
2PM 02/01/2013  Pen     85p
9AM 03/01/2013  Apple   25p
9AM 05/01/2013  Pencil  10p
9AM 05/01/2013  Pen     70p
2PM 05/01/2013  Pencil  15p    <- Notice there can be multiple price changes on the same day
...

[tblItems]:
Item    Category    Ratio
Orange  Fruit       1
Apple   Fruit       3
Pen     Stationary  2
Pencil  Stationary  5
...
```

### Problem

The end result is that I want to be able to see how the **average price of each category changes through time** - for example:

[image]

Specifically, the average price series of Fruits, for instance, should be calculated as the weighted average of Orange and Apple prices in a `Ratio` of 1:3. So in the end I'm looking to generate (via some combination of queries) the following table for the underlying data of the chart:

```
Timestamp   Fruit   Stationary
01/01/2013  40.0    80.0
02/01/2013  55.0    85.0
03/01/2013  50.0    85.0
04/01/2013  50.0    85.0
05/01/2013  50.0    75.0
...
(this data is also made up and so probably not consistent with the original example)
```

I've managed to get an inner join on the two tables, but not too sure how to proceed. My main problem is how to handle days with no prices changes such as 01/04/13. The average prices still exist, but is not getting picked up by any query I try.

So how to use queries to construct data for the chart?

Comment: Can you update your question and add your query? That would help.

Comment: Also, without seeing your query, I'd recommend using a left join instead of an inner join.  That *may* show days such as 01/04/13 depending on how your query is structured.

Comment: There's really nothing much to see - I've just done an inner join on `Item` but dont know how to proceed to get weighted averages etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One remark before we start on a solution: be careful not to use reserved words for field names. `Timestamp` is a reserved word. Access will let you name a column that way, but you may encounter strange issues later on, especially if you ever move to another database in the future or use some other tools that fetch data from your Access database.

So here, I renamed your `Timestamp` column to `DateTimeStamp`.

I think that your requirements would be more straightforward to implement in VBA rather than in pure SQL queries: while you can easily build a query that gets you the average of each category per day, you are going to struggle to fill-in the data for the days where you have no data.

#### Simple but incomplete SQL solution

However, maybe having these holes in your data isn't that much of an issue since the graph will simply skip those missing values (it's not like they would show up as a data value of 0.00).
In that case, the following query should give you the results:

```
SELECT Dateserial(Year([DateTimeStamp]), 
                  Month([DateTimeStamp]), 
                  Day([DateTimeStamp])) AS NormalisedDate,
       tblItems.Category,
       SUM([Price]*[Ratio])/SUM([Ratio]) AS AvgPrice
FROM   tblPriceChanges
       INNER JOIN tblItems
         ON tblPriceChanges.Item=tblItems.Item
GROUP  BY Dateserial(Year([DateTimeStamp]), 
                     Month([DateTimeStamp]), 
                     Day([DateTimeStamp])),
          tblItems.Category
```

Would result in the following:

```
NormalisedDate    Category     AvgPrice
01/01/2013        Fruit        35
01/01/2013        Stationary   80
02/01/2013        Fruit        55
02/01/2013        Stationary   85
03/01/2013        Fruit        25
05/01/2013        Stationary   22.0833333333333
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's **one main issue with your solution**: it fails to *carry forward absent price data* from the previous day. For instance, if on day 1, `apples` and `oranges` were both 50p but on day 2, `oranges` drop to 40p, the averaged series of your proposed solution would give the average price of `Fruits` on day 2 as 40p when it should be 45p. This is because it does not take into account that `apples` remain at 50p from the previous day since there is no data for `apples` on day 2 for the SQL `GROUP BY` operation.

Comment: @MiloChen you are right, but there is no way to do what you ask through a query in Access. You will have to drop down to VBA and track all the possible items for each and every day you need to plot, then add the missing information for each item for each day based on the average data for that item from the previous day... this is possible in VBA, but it's going to take some effort.

Comment: And one other thing: I see what you are trying to do but I have doubt that this is going to be a good thing. What about items that are no longer sold or have not been sold in a long time? Should they also be included? That means that just to plot a graph for January, you will have to include data from the beginning, in case you sold a widget 6 months ago that may influence the average price of the Stationary category if it's not included.... What about items that are sold on the 5th of the month but for which we have no data for the 1st-4th period? Should the system backtrack the price?

Comment: I guess my point is that -as a metric- the average price of a category doesn't look that interesting: you need to include a lot of data that is not relevant to the actual sales being made and you are bundling items that can have huge variations: fruits can be sold by the item or by weight, or by pre-packet bundles. In that case, you would have a single data point for an apple, but also for a kilo of apples, or a pre-packet bag of apples... What does the average price mean in that case? What about when you start selling Pineapples by the box? What will that mean for your average category price?